# Replace negative values by NaN on a raster (without converting it into an array first)

Tags: python, replace, nan, raster, rasterio

I want to replace all the negative files of a raster (tiff) file to no data values (nan), and save it into a new file (also tiff). I don't want to convert it into a numpy array first - I want to replace directly the pixel on the raster itself, using rasterio for instance.

I tried the following:

```
#Open the file with rasterio
raster_file = rasterio.open(r"path_to_file.tif")
#Read as raster
raster = raster_file.read(1)
#Assign 999 to all negative values
raster[raster <= 0] = 999
#Create a boolean mask
mask_boolean = (raster !=999)
# Write the mask back to the dataset:
raster.write_mask(mask_boolean)
raster.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use xarray:

```py
import xarray

# Open the file with xarray
raster_file = xarray.open_dataarray(path, engine="rasterio")
print(raster_file.min().data)
# > - 1

# Assign NaN to negative values
raster_file = raster_file.where(raster_file > 0)
print(raster_file.min().data)
# > 0
```

You will end up with a xarray representation of your raster filled with NaN.

However, you cannot change pixels values in place, you will have to save the raster back on disk.